# Fetching information from a facebook WebCal in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm building my first app which should fetch some events from a Facebook CalDAV. But I can't seem to define the source with EventKit. Am I reading the documentation wrong and is it only possible to get information from the iPhones calendar?

The source I'm trying to reach is:

[webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=614013015&key=AQCJQo9Dh5NqgP1Z](http://webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=614013015&key=AQCJQo9Dh5NqgP1Z)

Does it provide a problem that it is a webcal and not an official CalDAV standard?

Thanks in advance
-Villars

Answer (score 0):

I've looked it through and as I see it, EventKit doesn't give the option of connecting to a calendar outside iOS' own.